# how to make a flask route only callable by app

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

I am working on an app and I want to be able to edit a table of data using [flask jquery](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/jquery/) in the documentation they use a pattern:

controlers:

```
@GCInv.route('/_add_numbers')
def add_numbers():
    a = request.args.get('a', 0, type=int)
    b = request.args.get('b', 0, type=int)
    return jsonify(result=a + b)

@GCInv.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('testAJAX.html')
```

HTML:
<

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/test.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type=text/javascript>
  $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }}
</script>
<h1>jQuery Example</h1>
<p><input type=text size=5 name=a> +
   <input type=text size=5 name=b> =
   <span id=result>?</span>
<p><a href=# id=calculate>calculate server side</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Java Script:

```
 $(function() {
    $('a#calculate').bind('click', function() {
      $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_add_numbers', {
        a: $('input[name="a"]').val(),
        b: $('input[name="b"]').val()
      }, function(data) {
        $("#result").text(data.result);
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
```

in this example, it appears that users could call '_add_numbers' it seems like a security risk to leave this route open is there a way to make a decorator or make the route so it can only be called internally?

Comment: No matter the name, the function that your flask.route decorator it's going to use it's going to get called and you need to add that route somewhere - a form, a link, some JS. It's the way 'web' works. It's not a security matter.

Comment: Even if you create a private method, that method will end up being called in a route method, but this doesn't mean that a user will be able to call that private method directly because it's not defined as a route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# not callable, because only using app.route() decorator will expose it
def lets_do_something():
    # something just happened

    return True

@app.route('/callme')
def callme():
    lets_do_something()

    return render_template('calledit')
```